# Deletion of question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, deleted-questions, auto-delete

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3849893/792431

Why question with above link has been deleted? This question was asked in ISI UGA 2009 EXAM.

Comment: As to why it was closed, please read [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|126.8835).  Just because a problem statement appears in a textbook, or on an exam, does not make it a good question on math.se.  We need information only you can provide.

Answer (score 11):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/512127):

> The system will automatically delete closed, unlocked, and non-migrated questions that have zero or negative score, have no positively scored or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, were closed for any reason other than duplicate nine or more days ago, and haven't been edited in the past nine days.

(The timeline's a bit off since you deleted and the undeleted the question between when it was closed and when it was auto-deleted, but that's due to how the system "resets the count" when that happens.)